# Python: calculate averages based on dates and display according to month wise

Tags: python

I am basically new to python and I have the below requirement
I have dates from Jan to dec and average values for some itmes like

[image]

In the attached image there are 5 rows belongs to May month and 6 rows belongs to June month

How can we iterate and calculate the average on month wise, like I want to calculate Averages of Food, Drinks and wastage for the months of May and June(on month wise I have 12 months of data).

I need output like

```
Month       Food         Drink         wastage 
May-17       2.0          3.0            2.0 
June-17      2.5          2.5             3.0
```

Comment: Please post the actual data and description and not an image.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And please try to include critical information within the question, not a link to a picture.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, it is required that your question be clear. What is the format of that data, and what data structure is it in? (That information is critical, especially for dates.) Why is `-17` appended to the months in your example output? It is also highly encouraged that you show some of your work on the problem, preferably including a code attempt. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Input data and expected output do not make any sense. Look at the year

Answer (score 1):

First put your data into a panda data frame - I made up dummy data on my own - you need to figure out how to load your source. (from csv or excel).

Initiate the frame

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime   

 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start_date' : ['2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-02- 
    01','2018-03-10','2018-02-05'],'food' : [2, 2.5, 3, 2.4, 5, 4],'drinks' : 
    [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'wastage':[6,5,4,3,2,1]})
```

Make sure you have date format on your date column - in this my input was string so I needed to cast it (you need to use a different format here) see (bottom of documentation for date formats: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html )

```
 df1.Start_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Start_date, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would add a month column:
Edited with year:

```
df1["period"] = df1.Start_date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%b-%y'))

df1['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.Start_date).month
```

Apply group by and mean

```
 df1.groupby(['month']).mean() # for only month groupings

 df1.groupby(['period']).mean() # for output listed above
```

Comment: Well, good attempt. But OP silently mentioned displaying year as well. So should be grouped by on month and year both and display the dates in somewhat different format.

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar
df= pd.DataFrame({'date': ['6/8/2015','7/10/2018','6/5/2015'],'food':[1.5,2.5,3],'drinks':[2,2.4,3],'wastage':[2,2.5,3],})
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
df=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by=[df.date.dt.month.rename('month'),df.date.dt.year.rename('year')]).mean()).reset_index()
df['month'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
df['year']=df['year'].apply(str)
df['year']=df.year.str.replace("20","")
df['period'] = df[['month', 'year']].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x), axis=1)
df=df.drop(['year','month'],axis=1)
df=df.rename(index=str, columns={"period": "month"})
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
df[cols]
```

Output

```
    month   drinks  food    wastage
0   Jun-15  2.5    2.25     2.5
1   Jul-18  2.4    2.50     2.5
```